# How do I set NSNumberFormatter to display numbers using "万" (Japanese/Chinese 10,000 marker)?

Tags: ios, currency, nsnumberformatter

My iOS app displays different currencies (USD, JPY, AUD, EUR) in different localizations (`en_US`, `en_AU`, `ja_JP`, etc).

For Japanese region/language (both are set on my device), if I have:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
fmt.currencyCode = @"JPY";
NSString *labelText = [fmt stringFromNumber:@1000000];
```

My label text is `¥1,000,000`.  However, in Japanese and Chinese, numbers greater than 10,000 might be written `100万円`, which is the output I want.

Any idea what code I can write to get `100万円` as the output?

I'd like to avoid logic blocks in my code checking for locale/region, but I feel like that's what I'm coming up against (for example, using the method call `fmt.multipler = @(1/10000)` to divide 1,000,000 by 10,000 to get the right value).

Comment: Are you always expecting this format? (e.g. for a hundred yen, 100円?) Or do you want small values to look different from large ones?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like 100円 to show up as 100円, but if it is over 10,000 yen, it would go to 万円

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Up to date gist here: https://gist.github.com/fjolnir/cd72ea39be1476023adf

Old thread, but I came across it while looking for a solution so I figured I'd post my implementation.

The formatter itself does not handle placement of 円, but that's easy to do outside of it. (as the example below demonstrates)

The expected output of the below is:

```
2015-03-11 18:00:13.376 LENumberFormatter[82736:3604947] 12億3,460万円
2015-03-11 18:00:13.377 LENumberFormatter[82736:3604947] 25円
```

-

```
@import Foundation;
@import ObjectiveC.message;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, LENumberFormatterAbbreviationStyle) {
    kLEAbbreviateShort, // 2.5m
    kLEAbbreviateNormal // 2m 5k
};

@interface LENumberFormatter : NSNumberFormatter
@property(nonatomic) BOOL abbreviateLargeNumbers;
@property(nonatomic) LENumberFormatterAbbreviationStyle abbreviationStyle;
@end


@implementation LENumberFormatter
- (instancetype)init
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.abbreviationStyle = [self _usingKanjiNumbers]
                               ? kLEAbbreviateNormal
                               : kLEAbbreviateShort;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id const)aObj
{
    if(!_abbreviateLargeNumbers || ![aObj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        return [super stringForObjectValue:aObj];

    // Copy ourselves to get format the partial digits using the settings on self
    LENumberFormatter * const partialFormatter = [self copy];
    partialFormatter.currencySymbol = @"";
    if(_abbreviationStyle == kLEAbbreviateNormal)
        partialFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;

    NSString *(^partialFormat)(NSNumber*) = ^(NSNumber *num) {
        NSString *(*superImp)(struct objc_super*,SEL,NSNumber*) = (void*)&objc_msgSendSuper;
        return superImp(&(struct objc_super) { partialFormatter, self.superclass }, _cmd, num);
    };

    double n = [aObj doubleValue];
    BOOL const shortFormat = _abbreviationStyle == kLEAbbreviateShort;

    NSDictionary * const separators         = [self _localizedGroupingSeparators];
    NSArray      * const separatorExponents = [separators.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    BOOL const currencySymbolIsSuffix = [self.positiveFormat hasSuffix:@"¤"];
    NSMutableString * const result = currencySymbolIsSuffix || self.numberStyle != NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle
                                   ? [NSMutableString new]
                                   : [self.currencySymbol mutableCopy];
    NSUInteger significantDigits = 0;
    NSNumber *lastExp = nil;
    for(NSNumber *exp in separatorExponents.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
        double divisor = pow(10, exp.shortValue);
        if(divisor > n)
            continue;

        if(lastExp)
            significantDigits += lastExp.doubleValue - exp.doubleValue;
        lastExp = exp;

        if(self.usesSignificantDigits && significantDigits >= self.maximumSignificantDigits)
            break;

        double partialNum = shortFormat
                          ? n/divisor
                          : floor(n/divisor);
        NSString * const digits = [self _groupRecursively] && ![exp isEqual:@0]
                                ? [partialFormatter stringFromNumber:@(partialNum)]
                                : partialFormat(@(partialNum));
        [result appendFormat:@"%@%@", digits, separators[exp]];

        n = fmod(n, divisor);

        if(shortFormat)
            break; // Just use a float+first hit

        // If we make it here, partialNum is integral and we can use log10 to find the number of digits
        significantDigits += log10(partialNum) + 1;
        partialFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits -= digits.length;

    }
    if(n > 0
       && !shortFormat
       && (!self.usesSignificantDigits || significantDigits < self.maximumSignificantDigits))
    {
        partialFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = self.maximumFractionDigits;
        [result appendString:partialFormat(@(n))];
    }
    if(self.numberStyle == NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle && currencySymbolIsSuffix && self.currencySymbol)
        [result appendString:self.currencySymbol];

    return result.length > 0
         ? [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
         : [super stringForObjectValue:aObj];
}

- (BOOL)_usingKanjiNumbers
{
    return [self.locale.localeIdentifier rangeOfString:@"^(ja|zh)_"
                                               options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}
- (NSDictionary *)_localizedGroupingSeparators
{
    if(self._usingKanjiNumbers)
        return @{ @2: @"百", @3: @"千", @4: @"万", @8: @"億" };
    else {
        NSBundle * const bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class];
        return @{ 
            @3: [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"thousandSuffix" value:@"k " table:nil],
            @6: [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"millionSuffix"  value:@"m " table:nil]
        };
    }
}

- (BOOL)_groupRecursively
{
    // Return _usingKanjiNumbers if you want:
    // 12億3千4百56万7千8百90
    // Rather than:
    // 1億2,3456万7千8百90
    return NO;
}

- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone * const)aZone
{
    LENumberFormatter * const copy = [super copyWithZone:aZone];
    copy.abbreviateLargeNumbers = _abbreviateLargeNumbers;
    copy.abbreviationStyle      = _abbreviationStyle;
    return copy;
}
@end


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        LENumberFormatter * const f = [LENumberFormatter new];
        f.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];
//        f.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
        f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
        f.abbreviateLargeNumbers = YES;
        f.abbreviationStyle = kLEAbbreviateNormal; // Automatic if using system locale
        f.maximumSignificantDigits = 5;
        f.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
//        f.currencyCode   = @"JPY";
//        f.currencySymbol = @"¥";

        if([f.locale.localeIdentifier hasPrefix:@"ja"]) {
            f.positiveFormat = @"#,##0¤";
            if([f.currencyCode isEqualToString:@"JPY"])
                // We allow ourselves this special case because *日本円 just looks dumb
                f.currencySymbol = @"円";
            else
                f.currencySymbol = [f.locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode
                                          value:f.currencyCode];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", [f stringFromNumber:@1234567890]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [f stringFromNumber:@25]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I subclassed `NSNumberFormatter` and overrode `stringWithNumber:`.

Here is the relevant code I used to re-configure the `NSNumberFormatter` when the currency code is `JPY`.

```
  NSString *localeString = [self.locale localeIdentifier];
  if ([localeString isEqualToString:@"ja_JP"])
  {
    // 1-oku
    if (num >= 100000000)
    {
      self.negativeFormat = @"-#,###0億円";
      self.positiveFormat = @"#,###0億円";
      self.multiplier = @(1.0f/100000000.0f);
    }
    // 1-man
    else if (num >= 10000)
    {
      self.negativeFormat = @"-#,###0万円";
      self.positiveFormat = @"#,###0万円";
      self.multiplier = @(1.0f/10000.0f);
    }
    // Less than 10,000
    else
    {
      self.negativeFormat = @"-#,###0円";
      self.positiveFormat = @"#,###0円";
    }
  }
  // This could be en_AU, en_UK, en_US -- but all use "million yen"
  else if ([localeString hasPrefix:@"en"])
  {
    // We only care about 1M JPY+
    if (num >= 1000000)
    {
      self.negativeFormat = @"-¥#,###0M";
      self.positiveFormat = @"¥#,###0M";
      self.multiplier = @(1.0f/1000000.0f);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This implementation is not ideal as values like １２億３４６０万円 are not possible. Check @Fjölnir's implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I just selected it as the correct answer - it's been awhile since I've looked at this code, but I'm glad that this question has become the defacto Google destination for people trying to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

I guess "man" price notation is similar to european "K" notation (which is not so common however). In that sense, I guess there is no standard for a some "short price/number" notation, so it is not included in standard culture formatters and format specifiers. I guess standards are oriented to some reasonable common denominator and `万円` doesn't fit well there. Also it's rather strange that standard `¥` symbol is used in front, while `円` is used after price value.

Standards are pretty rigid stuff, so I would not consider for support for `万円` style currency support in near future. So, I think for now there is only "manual" solution to this.

P.S. I guess there should be some third-party library available for that, because it must be a pretty common task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Possibly I need an NSNumberFormatter subclass to help that has special behaviors in Chinese/Japanese language/regions.

Comment: In Japan [almost] always the prices equal or above 10000 are expressed in 万. Japanese people don't even think in 10 thousands but in 万. This being said I would consider a *must* requirement to express quantities in 万　when localization `ja_JP` is used.

Comment: I know about Japan specifics, I guess standards are oriented to some reasonable common denominator and `万円` doesn't fit well there.

Comment: Yeah, it's generally disappointing to me that I can set the number of decimals in a grouping, but that the `ja_JP` localization does not include support for this.  Subclass time??